# Consulta eloquent tablas relacionadas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta entre diferentes tablas relacionadas.

```
$viajes = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%')
                 ->where('pro','like', '%'.$pro.'%')
                 ->whereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('provincia', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');})
                 ->whereHas('direccionesdes', function($q) use ($destino){$q->Where('provincia', 'like', '%'.$destino.'%');})
                 ->paginate(250);
```

Este código funciona perfectamente.

La cuestion es que me gustaría poder poder reutilizar las variables "origen" y "destino" para poder buscar en diferentes columnas.
Este código funciona bien, me permite buscar en las columnas "provincia" "población" y "pais" con la misma variable.

```
$viajes = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%')
                 ->where('pro','like', '%'.$pro.'%')
                 ->whereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('provincia', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');})
                 ->orwhereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('poblacion', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');})
                 ->orwhereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('pais', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');})
                 ->paginate(250);
```

Pero cuando intento añadir la siguiente tabla relacionada la consulta deja de funcionar y ya no filtra ningún resultado.

```
$viajes = Viaje::where('cli','like', '%'.$cliente.'%')
                 ->where('pro','like', '%'.$pro.'%')
                 ->whereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('provincia', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');})
                 ->orwhereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('poblacion', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');})
                 ->orwhereHas('direccionescar', function($q) use ($origen){$q->Where('pais', 'like', '%'.$origen.'%');})
                 ->whereHas('direccionesdes', function($q) use ($destino){$q->Where('provincia', 'like', '%'.$destino.'%');})
                 ->orwhereHas('direccionesdes', function($q) use ($destino){$q->Where('poblacion', 'like', '%'.$destino.'%');})
                 ->orwhereHas('direccionesdes', function($q) use ($destino){$q->Where('pais', 'like', '%'.$destino.'%');})
                 ->paginate(250);
```